# Is there any video-chat-via-lan software?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any video-chat-via-LAN application that doesn't require an Internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

> Ekiga (formely known as GnomeMeeting) is an open source SoftPhone,
>   Video Conferencing and Instant Messenger application over the
>   Internet.
>
> It supports HD sound quality and video up to DVD size and quality.
>
> It is interoperable with many other standard compliant softwares,
>   hardwares and service providers as it uses both the major telephony
>   standards (SIP and H.323).<sup>1</sup>

To install, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install ekiga
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I have read about some jabber servers with videochat support.

May be, the [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) jabber server includes support for video.

Have a look at this, too:

In [this site](http://www.jabber-server.de/red5/), they say that using a Red5 plugin, the jabber server supports videochat.